# multiTenant database in hibernate

Tags: transactions, multi-tenant

Can anyone show me a example for multiTenant Database with Hibernate and using spring Hibernate Txmanager for tx Mgmt.

My requirements are

thers master database which is always open and contains info about tenant Db.
on hitting master for first time get db info of specific tenant and generate session ZFactory for the tenant and rest request shall be served via tenant Sessions.
i have implementated

but cudn't get my transaction manager working for tenant Dbs.

```
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>beans.table</value>
            <value>beans.views</value>
        </array>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>

            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop> -->
            <prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="tenantSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>beans.table</value>
            <value>views</value>
        </array>
    </property>

    <!--<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />-->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>

            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop> -->
            <prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_size">30</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">factory.MultiTenantIdentifierResolver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">factory.MultiTenantConnectionProvider</prop>


        </props>
    </property>




</bean>
<!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
<!-- <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" /> spring.fix.HibernateTransactionManager 
    com.my.hibernate4.spring.fix.HibernateTransactionManager"> <property name="sessionFactory" 
    ref="sessionFactory" /> -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="tenantTransactionManager"
      class="factory.MultiTenantHibernateTxManager" p:autodetectDataSource="false">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="tenantSessionFactory"  />

</bean>


<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="tenantTransactionManager"
                      proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: You shouldn't connect to the root database. Instead you should connect directly to the correct pdb in the first place.

Comment: for connecting to root db i have already made different session factory in MultiTenantConnectionProvider implementaion class so from there i get DataSourceDynmically and provide Connection for the tenantSessionFactory.

Comment: I cant connect to db directly.. coz my application login is based on root db and rest part is based upon tenantDb. based upon the user supporting the specific tenant.

Comment: My tenantSessionFactory works and gets created swiftly the major problem me facing is in managaing the transaction over that mulitTenantSession. i unable to manage transaction over that session. everytime i need to openNewSession as i m unable to get session in Current Context. which is to be maintained by transaction manager/SessionHolder

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution at Spring Forum (my nickname is deggesim) -> http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/114116-sessionfactory-configured-for-multi-tenancy-but-no-tenant-identifier-specified